# Odd centering CSS problem in modern non-Chrome browsers?

Tags: css, margin, centering

For some reason, I have this one webpage which renders something great in Chrome, but completely different on FireFox and IE.

The effect may be seen [here](http://www.tiletabs.com/v2.htm).

The other browsers appear to remove my margin centering of my `header` and `footer` elements.

Is there a particular reason this is only working in Chrome?

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>TileTabs</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/v2.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/veramono.css" type="text/css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tile_interaction.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="images/logo/logo_v3.png" alt="logo" />
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="tile">
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <a class="emailus" href="index.htm">Home</a> | <a class="emailus" href="about.htm">About</a> | <a class="emailus" href="contact.htm">Contact</a>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #F6F6F6;
    font-family: 'BitstreamVeraSansMonoRoman', 'Myriad-Pro', 'Myriad', helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

header {
    width: 920px;
    background: #999;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;

    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;


}

#content {
    width: 920px;
    height: 760px;
    background: #999;
    margin: 0px auto;
}

footer {
    width: 920px;
    background: #999;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;

    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;    
}

li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 34px;
}

.tile {
    cursor: pointer;
    background: red;
    border: 2px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<header>` and `<footer>` tags are new (HTML5)

For older browsers that don't support HTML5 just use standard divs.

If you want to still use `<header>` and `<footer>` you can use the following code to make it work for browsers that don't support the HTML5 tags.

```
<script>
document.createElement('header');
document.createElement('footer');
</script>
```

Comment: OK, I heard that it was ok to use these without consequence.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Older browsers won't freak out over using HTML5 tags, they just won't apply any CSS you have for them.

Comment: Ah, makes sense then.  That explains why I noticed the centering being thrown off.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

get rid of the header tags

```
<-- <header> --!>   
<-- </header> --!>
```

and place the picture inside of the content tag like so, also center the picture with some css

```
<div id="content">
        <img src="images/logo/logo_v3.png" alt="logo" /> 
        <ul>
           ...
```

tags are part of HTML5 which are not yet fully supported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that IE doesn't fully support (if at all) the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags. I'm not sure about Firefox 3.x, but this works fine in the current beta of Firefox 4.